# Javascript confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I want to add a confirm dialog to a delete button to ask the user whether it is ok or not deleting the selected item.

If not, nothing should happend, else a url should be executed.

I know how to realize this via some Javascript code but I am looking for a solution that has less code. I mean e.g. :

```
<a href="mysite.de/xy/delete" onClick="...">Delete</a>
```

Is it possible to put the whole functionality in the `onClick` element without having some extra Javascript in the header?

Comment: not expert in javascript. However wouldn't it be possible to write an function which is called in onClick?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Better (though far from ideal!): turn it around. Don't let the link do anything, unless you got JavaScript:

```
<a href="#" 
  onclick="if confirm('Sure?') { window.location='http://mysite.de/xy/delete';}">
    Click to delete
</a>
```

This at least prevents the link to work without JavaScript. This also reduces the risk of the link accidentally being crawled by Google, or even by some local plugin. (Image if you had a plugin that would try to load/show as thumbnail) the target page on hover of a link!)

Still, this solution is not ideal. You will actually browse to the url, and the url might show up in the history because of that. You could actually delete Bob, create a new Bob, and then delete that one by accident by just clicking 'back' in the browser!

A better option would be to use JavaScript or a form to post the desired action. You can make a request to the server with the POST method, or arguably better, the DELETE method. That should also prevent the urls from being indexed.

Comment: Agreed, this is a bit better. There are potential risks associated with the page appearing in the browser history for instance.

Comment: I am using php to print the link, any idea why this isn't working?: echo '<a class="garbage" href="#" onclick="if(confirm("Sure?")){ window.location="http://www.web.de";}">';

Comment: You need to escape your quotes around "Sure?" and "web.de".

Comment: Or use single quotes, like I did in my answer.

Answer (score 29):

You can `return` the [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Window.confirm) (which returns `true`/`false`), like this:

```
<a href="mysite.de/xy/delete" onClick="return confirm('You sure??');">Delete</a>
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/eJzXX/)

Comment: Technically this will work, but I still can't recommend this way, as it isn't best practice. Actions should really be posted to the server.

Comment: I would think `DELETE` rather than `GET` or `POST`…

Answer (score 5):

Consider what happens if the user has javascript disabled, or if google comes along and spiders the link. Will your entity be deleted?

A better way would be to post a form to delete.

Comment: I do not think that this delete link is public, so it should be no problem.

Comment: I need the feature for a backend service where javascript has to be enabled

Comment: This assumes there's no other security in place...though I do agree POST should be used for actions.

Comment: @elusive: It's not clear from the question whether or not the functionality will be publicly accessible.

Comment: Making delete actions accessible to the public is a very rare decision. Granting access to such a page to search engine spiders should be prevented either way, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

There is a jQuery plugin that does just that: [jquery.confirm](https://github.com/myclabs/jquery.confirm).

Example:

```
<a href="home" class="confirm">Go to home</a>
```

JS code:

```
$('.confirm').confirm();
```

[image: screenshot]

If the user confirms, he is redirected to the link of the `<a>`, else nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:
Download a bootboxjs from:[1]: http://bootboxjs.com/

Create the Button (HTML)

```
<button type="submit" id="btn">Delete</button>
```

Call the Dialog:

```
  var myBtn = document.getElementById('btn');


  myBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      bootbox.confirm({
          size: "small",
          message: "Are you sure?",
          callback: function (result) {
              /* result is a boolean; true = OK, false = Cancel*/
              if (result == true) {
                  alert("ok pressed");
              }
              else {
                  alert("cancel pressed");
              }
          }
      })
  });
```