# Add a alert box with "save" or "no"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, messagebox

My web page deletes a row in a table and save it automatically in database. I need a `messageBox` after clicking on delete button, with two buttons "save" and "No".
Delete function on jsp is below:

```
function deleteFileRow(rowCount)
{
 $.ajax(
    {
      url: 'deleteRow.htm?rowIndex='+rowCount+"&action=delete&id="+${id},
       success: function(data)
       {
          document.location.reload();
       }
    });
}
```

Please help me in doing this.

Comment: Why don't you go for [jquery alert](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) ?

Comment: or you can use simple `confirm` box: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292455/javascript-confirm-dialog

Comment: But I believe the labels in `confirm` box may not be customizable !

Comment: calling function is:   <a href=# onclick=deleteFileRow('"+maxRowCount+"')><img src=images/icons/delete.png></a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/print/alert-response-and-other-popup-windows-in-acrobat-javascript) you can find how to pop a messageBox with yes/no and question in javascript
and you can use that if you aren't determined on "save"/"no"

```
var nRslt = app.alert ("Press \"yes\" to save\n" + "Press \"No\" to delete";, 2, 2, "Submit Validation"); 
if(nRslt == 4) { // User Pressed Yes, Do submission 
    this.submitForm(...); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use jquery confirm box to add yes or no.

```
ConfirmDialog('Are you sure');

function ConfirmDialog(message){
$('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
                .html('<div><h6>'+message+'?</h6></div>')
                .dialog({
                    modal: true, title: 'Delete message', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                    width: 'auto', resizable: false,
                    buttons: {
                        Yes: function () {
                            // $(obj).removeAttr('onclick');                                
                            // $(obj).parents('.Parent').remove();

                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        },
                        No: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    },
                    close: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).remove();
                    }
                });
};
```

ref http://jsfiddle.net/nM3Zc/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved with the following code:

```
function deleteFileRow(rowCount){
var stay=confirm("Are you sure, You want to delete Row? Click "ok" to confirm, "cancel" Otherwise")
if(stay)
{
        $.ajax({
        url: 'deleteRow.htm?rowIndex='+rowCount+"&action=delete&testid="+${testid},
        success: function(data) {
            document.location.reload();
        }
        });
}
}
```

Ajax call would be inside "confirm".